# Panda dataFrame check if value exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this.

```
Date         |   Hour
--------------------------
11/06/2020   |   13
17/06/2020   |   12
02/07/2020   |   9
```

I wanna check if the Date exists where the Hour is also below 10. Below is my code, but it was wrong.

```
if((dataFrame['Hour'] < 10).any() & (dataFrame['Date'] == date).any()):
            point = 1
```

Kindly need some helps from you guys. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter a Data Frame with multiple conditions with & and | operators, or use the [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method, then check the length of the resulting Data Frame for the number of matching rows.

Method 1: Using & operator

```python
import pandas as pd

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['11/06/2020', '17/06/2020', '02/07/2020'],
    'Hour': [13, 12, 9]
})

date = '02/07/2020' # target date to match

if len(dataFrame[(dataFrame['Hour'] < 10) & (dataFrame['Date'] == date)]) != 0:
  # at least one row in dataframe matches both conditions
  point = 1
else:
  point = 0
```

Method 2: Using query() method.

```python
results = dataFrame.query(f"Hour  < 10 and Date == '{date}'")
if len(results) != 0:
  print("match")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `isinstance` as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 11), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 17), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 12), 0],
                    'Hour':[13, 12, 9, 5, 3]})

df.loc[df.Hour < 10, 'Date'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime.datetime))
```

**df:**

|  | Date | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-06-11 00:00:00 | 13 |
| 1 | 2020-06-17 00:00:00 | 12 |
| 2 | 2020-07-02 00:00:00 | 9 |
| 3 | 2020-07-12 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 4 | 0 | 3 |

---

**Result:**

```
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

---

**Issues:**

If the only non-datetime values in column "Date" are of type `None` as in the case of `None` and `np.nan`, pandas will assume the entire column is type `datetime` and this method will not work as intended. To solves this problem replace `None` values with `0`.

**Solution:**

```
df.loc[df.Hour < 10, 'Date'].replace(np.nan, 0).apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime.datetime))
```